# Quiero saber como usar el curl de Mercado Pago y ponerlo en un json

Tags: php, mercadopago, backend

curl -X GET
'https://api.mercadopago.com/payments/{id}'
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_ENV'

Quiero obtener los datos del pago en un json.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: dejo el codigo que si funciona:

```
$ACCESS_TOKEN="tu_token_aqui"; //aqui cargamos el token
    $curl = curl_init(); //iniciamos la funcion curl
    
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
//ahora vamos a definir las opciones de conexion de curl
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/14700412814", //aqui iria el id de tu pago
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", // el metodo a usar, si mercadopago dice que es post, se cambia GET por POST.
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, //esto es importante para que no imprima en pantalla y guarde el resultado en una variable
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0, 
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$ACCESS_TOKEN
      ),
    ));
    
    
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl); //ejecutar CURL
    $json_data = json_decode($response, true); //a la respuesta obtenida de CURL la guardamos en una variable con formato json.
    
    //ahora las imprimimos en pantalla
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json_data); 
    echo "</pre>";
    //ahora por ejemplo, queremos obtener el status de pago, hacemos esto:
    $status=$json_data["status"];  
    //aqui se pueden ver todas las otras variables que obtenemos de un pago:
    //https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/manage-account/account/retrieving-payments
```

Espero le sirva a alguien.
para ver el resto de opciones de CURL se puede googlear cada una o ver la documentacion aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Podrias explicar como funciona el codigo? Ya que el OP dice "*Quisiera saber como usar*"

Comment: hola amigo ya lo resolvi si quieres te mando el codigo por interno

Comment: Hola @Farsser, claro, por favor, si no por email a seba.ocano@gmail.com

Comment: @JuanRivera ahi deje un poco mas claro el funcionamiento del codigo que logre que me funcionara en mi proyecto. saludos!